# Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS Installer is not detecting my SSDs

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, ssd, nvme, msi

recently i brought a new MSI GE68HX 062US laptop. I tried dual booting ubuntu (alongside windows) but the installer is not detecting my SSDs(both). I tried disabling the fast boot and secure boot, tried updating the firmware, but nothing worked. I also tried searching on the internet, but nothing actually worked.

---

SSDs - NVMe Samsung 980 PRO (disk 0), Samsung MZVL41TOHBLB-00BTW

BIOS version - AMI - E15M2IMS.10C

BIOS mode - UEFI

---

other info:

All this time i am installing it using an USB that contains the ISO image formatted using rufus

I tried installing ubuntu 22.04, and it is detecting both the SSD. But i specifically want 20.04 coz ROS neotic works only on 20.04

I tried to switch the SATA settings from RAID to AHCI but there is not such SATA settings in the BIOS, I later contacted the MSI team, and they said the BIOS automatically switches to AHCI so there is no need to manually switch.

I am just a beginner in this.

---

I hv been stuck here for days. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Check if Bitlocker is turned on in Windows. Some computers ship with bitlocker turned on. You will need t oturn it off from within windows if it is turned on.

Comment: Yeah, i tried that but there is no bitlocker option in windows

Comment: Please boot from the Live Ubuntu USB and use the "Try Ubuntu" option without installing. Then open the app Gparted. On the top right drop down, select the first SSD and then take a screenshot of that window. [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1486247/edit) and add the screenshot using the picture icon above the edit window.

Comment: Also make sure that the two SSDs are not configured in RAID formation in the UEFI (BIOS).

Comment: See [windows support on how to turn Bitlocker on and off](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-on-device-encryption-0c453637-bc88-5f74-5105-741561aae838#ID0EBD=Windows_11).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)